# File-Recovery in Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

What are good software-solutions in recovering deleted files in Ubuntu on ext3-/ext4- and ntfs-filesystems?

I've been looking for diverse programs, but I couldn't find good ones so far.

TIA

Comment: Take a look at [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Answer (score 1):

Look to this side:

```
extundelete --restore-all /dev/sdb1
```